# Simple Wireless Ad-Hoc Network in OMNet++/INET - how to send message/packet?

Tags: omnet++, inet

I want to create a simple wireless ad-hoc network in Omnet++ using inet.
What the network should do is:

- have multiple hosts that can send messages wirelessly to all hosts in range
- the hosts receive the message and forward it to my c++ application, where I use the content to determine what to do with it
- collisions (i. e. hosts receiving multiple messages at the same time) should be modelled, so that the affected messages can't be used

I don't care about the protocols that are used under the hood, I just want to model this behaviour in the easiest way possible to see if I can implement some kind of TDMA-protocol in my application.

I already set up a basic network, but now I don't understand how I can send simple messages (packets?) to all hosts in range. This is what I have so far:

**MyApp.cc:**

```
#include <omnetpp.h>
#include "inet/common/packet/Packet.h"

using namespace omnetpp;

class MyApp: public cSimpleModule {

    protected:
        virtual void initialize() override;
        virtual void handleMessage(cMessage *msg) override;

};

Define_Module(MyApp);

void MyApp::initialize() {

    EV << "Initialize called \n";
    inet::Packet *outPacket = new inet::Packet("TEST");

    // How to send this packet to all hosts now?
}

void MyApp::handleMessage(cMessage *msg) {

    EV << "handleMessage called \n";

}
```

**myNetwork.ned**

```
package mysimpleproject;

import inet.node.inet.INetworkNode;
import inet.physicallayer.contract.packetlevel.IRadioMedium;
import inet.networklayer.configurator.ipv4.Ipv4NetworkConfigurator;


network myNetwork {
    submodules:
        configurator: Ipv4NetworkConfigurator {
            @display("p=580,200");
        }
        radioMedium: <default("UnitDiskRadioMedium")> like IRadioMedium {
            @display("p=300,200");
        }
        hostA: <default("WirelessHost")> like INetworkNode {
            @display("p=50,100");
        }
        hostB: <default("WirelessHost")> like INetworkNode {
            @display("p=100,100");
        }
}
```

**myApp.ned**

```
package mysimpleproject;
import inet.applications.contract.IApp;

simple MyApp like IApp {

    gates:
        input socketIn;
        output socketOut;
}
```

**omnetpp.ini**

```
[General]
network = myNetwork

**.wlan[0].typename = "AckingWirelessInterface"
**.wlan[0].bitrate = 1000000bps
**.wlan[0].radio.transmitter.communicationRange = 100m

**.numApps = 1
**.app[0].typename = "MyApp"
```

I haven't found any real documentation on that as well (the inet Tutorials and even Developer's Guide do not show complete c++ code, so it's really hard to understand how to implement even these basic things), so if someone has more reference where I can read up on that it would also be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Your question can be formulated differently. Independent of the underlying technology (i.e. wireless or wired), the question is:

How do I send a UDP packet from an application to all other hosts in a network. And the answer is: **use the broadcast IP address (255.255.255.255) as the destination address** in your application. The underlying protocol will handle the task to send it out to each node in the range.